# "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" when running with py.test under /test folder

Tags: python, pytest

I have a class `Foo` which lives in `Src/Projects/SomeProject/Foo.py`

I have a class `FooTest(unittest.TestCase)` which lives in:

```
Src/Projects/SomeProject/tests/FooTest.py
```

When I run it with pytest (I just type 'py.test' in Src to run all tests), I get:

```
 def setUp(self):
     self.foo = Foo()
     TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

(I have `from Foo import Foo` in `FooTest.py` and `Foo.py` is in `sys.path`.

But when I run it with python: `python Src/Projects/SomeProject/tests/FooTest.py` everything works.)

Also, if I just move FooTest.py to `Src/Projects/SomeProject` then running with py.test suddenly works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your python path; some other `Foo.Foo` is being found before your module `Foo`.

Alternatively, in a `try`/`except TypeError` suite, print out the path of the offending module:

```
def setUp(self):
    try:
        self.foo = Foo()
    except TypeError:
        # What module Foo is this?
        print Foo.__file__
        raise
```

Comment: Well, I solved the problem by renaming Foo.py to FooComponent.py;
I think that it's not that I had another Foo.Foo, it's just that the project folder is named Foo as well, and that messed things up. (the file was in Src/Projects/Foo/Foo.py)
Any idea why this causes the error?

Comment: `Src/Projects` is probably listed your python path, coming before `Src/Projects/SomeProject`; check `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1):

I use the same naming convention, and I had the same problem.
I solved by instantiating the the object Foo by calling self.foo = Foo.Foo()